# Describe a topic in one sentence.

Tags: soft-question, big-picture, big-list

When you study a topic for the first time, it can be difficult to pick up the motivations and to understand where everything is going. Once you have some experience, however, you get that good high-level view (sometimes!) What I'm looking for are good one-sentence descriptions about a topic that deliver the (or one of the) main punchlines for that topic.

For example, when I look back at linear algebra, the punchline I take away is "Any nice function you can come up with is linear." After all, multilinear functions, symmetric functions, and alternating functions are essentially just linear functions on a different vector space. Another big punchline is "Avoid bases whenever possible."

What other punchlines can you deliver for various topics/fields?

Comment: This is a very good question, but to be useful and not just fun one should look critically at many of the answers below.

Comment: Gil, I am very skeptical about the value of this question. I don't think many of the answers given are that useful, because one won't get the punchlines unless one has acquired experience in the subject (and then, why would you need the punchline?). 

Comment: @Todd: to get fodder for a cocktail party level conversation....

Comment: @Suvrit: I guess it would be more of a "Big-Bang-Theory"-kind of party ;-)

Answer (score 55):

Homological algebra - In an abelian category, the difference between what you wish was true and what IS true is measured by a homology group.

Comment: May I ask, what is it that one wishes to be true (in an abelian category)?

Comment: @Colin: One wants certain functors to be exact, e.g., the Hom-functor gives Exts, tensoring with a module gives Tor.

Comment: Those are certainly the examples that give the most classical derived functors, but I think this platitude is more helpful when applied to a question which isn't obviously measured by a homology group.  

Comment: For example, once I was comparing $\overline{I\cap J}$ to $\overline{I}\cap \overline{J}$, where the bar denotes taking the associated graded module with respect to some filtration of $R$-ideals $I$ and $J$.  I suspected that there was some homology group which vanished exactly when those coincided, and I was correct (it was a rather complicated $Tor$).

Comment: What would be the difference measured by cohomology groups?

Comment: In an abelian category, a chain complex can be made into a cochain complex by flipping the sign of the indices.  So, there's no concrete difference between homology groups and cohomology groups.  (Though, in specific examples, usually one numbering is better and so a group feels more homological or cohomological)

Answer (score 46):

Functional analysis: Everything you know from linear algebra is true, under the right conditions; otherwise it's false.

Comment: And he gets 1 point for THIS. Might as well say,"Topology.Everything you know from calculus is true under the right conditionn.Otherwise it's false," I give up.........

Comment: Like MO points are the end-all and be-all of existence.

Comment: One difference is that whereas most linear algebra concepts generalize nicely to, say, Banach spaces, differentiation, perhaps the most basic concept of calculus, doesn't make sense in a topological space.

Comment: @gowers Ok,my statement was too nonspecific. I should have wrote,"Everything you know about open and closed intervals from calculus is true under the right conditions;otherwise it's false."

Comment: I like this one because despite its tautological flavor, it is not. 

Comment: ... differentiation being just another linear operator.... under the right conditions. :)

Answer (score 42):

Complex Analysis: Holomorphic functions are just rotations and dilations up to the first order.

Hold on...

Calculus: Differentiation is approximation by a linear map.

Comment: I like your description of calculus -- I am teaching multivariable calculus this semester, and I think the students have a hard time accepting that the "right" definition of differentiability is that a good linear approximation exists, instead of the more natural-seeming idea that all of the first partials exist.

Comment: About that description of complex analysis, see Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis*. 

Comment: @Gabe: I'm teaching multivariable calculus this semester too, but I defined the derivative to be the linear approximation first, and then introduced partial derivatives as a useful computational technique.

Comment: Damn,your first is basically one of the ones I gave below only with more detail. I'm a very firm believer in the geometric approach to classical complex analysis,especially in an undergraduate course.To me,this is really what makes complex analysis different from real analysis:The directness of the connection between the geometry of the plane and the analytic component in C. As for your second,I was first taught it in vector calculus by Josef Dodzuik and it's never lead me wrong. 

Comment: How can we describe a second-order derivative?

Comment: Colin: when I think of Hessians, I think of billowing clouds. (I'm not sure how easy that is to grasp. Think of an expanding cloud of smoke, and how molecules are pushing away from each other as seen from the perspective of projecting their trajectories down onto the tangent plane at a given molecule at a given instant. The behavior is locally given by fundamental ellipsoids, corresponding to a diagonalization of a matrix of second partials.) 

Answer (score 41):

Lie groups: Think locally, act globally. ;)

Comment: This applies to many other areas as well.

Comment: @Gil I totally agree.In fact,this can be the slogan for topology in general with some slight modifications.

Comment: A slight variant of it has been proposed elsewhere:  http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5295.

Comment: Less catchy, but: "think at the identity, act globally" is more specific to Lie theory.

Answer (score 39):

Complex Analysis:  Taylor series behave the way you want them to in real analysis.

Comment: When I was taking complex analysis, I remember someone saying "Complex analysis is the Disneyland of mathematics" because so many incredible theorems turn out to be true.

Comment: Every complex differentiable function is complex analytic. So we call this common concept as "holomorphic".

Answer (score 39):

Real Analysis: Get your hypotheses right, or suffer the counter-examples!

Measure Theory: "Every [measurable] set is nearly a finite union of intervals; every [measurable] function is nearly continuous; every convergent sequence of [measurable] functions is nearly uniformly convergent." -- J.E. Littlewood

Comment: Not to disparage the quote, but I find it funny that a function that is nowhere continuous (such as x=0 if rational, 1 otherwise) can be called 'nearly continuous'.

Comment: It's a question of where you put the quantifiers. For almost every point, the value is almost the same as it is at almost every nearby point.

Comment: and finally someone precisely explains why I don't like real analysis ;)

Answer (score 37):

One punchline in algebraic geometry is that all commutative rings are actually the ring of functions on some space.

Answer (score 30):

Analytic combinatorics: generating functions are awesome.

("generating functions are awesome" is actually the title of a talk I gave a couple weeks ago.)

Comment: Could you please add a link to that talk or some additional material on the matter? Thank you!

Comment: This was a "chalk talk" so I can't make the notes available.  The best introduction I know is Wilf's book generatingfunctionology, which can be downloaded from his web page.

Comment: There is also the book by Flajolet and Sedgewick, which is available at http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html

Comment: I can't believe this guy puts down a high school slogan and gets 13 points for it and I got downvoted for "Probability is real analysis with the concept of an expectation." 

Comment: @Andrew L : While I didn't vote this answer up, it is at least (arguably) correct.  Your answer, on the other hand, reveals a profound misunderstanding of probability theory.  Though probability theory uses many tools from real analysis (eg measure theory), the way it uses those tools and the intuition/philosophical explanation behind them is completely different from those of traditional real analysis.  Not to mention that your answer pretends there doesn't exist a giant field of finitary probability that is much more closely connected with combinatorics than with real analysis.

Comment: I can't believe someone would come along a *year* later and make this comment.

Comment: @Michael : Obviously, you have not been following the saga of Andrew L...

Comment: @Andy Wise-ass comment to Micheal aside,you made a very fair objection above. Discrete probability is fully half the science.I could counter it by saying combinatorics is essentially analysis on finite sets,but that's a real stretch.

Answer (score 30):

Operator theory: all separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are isomorphic, but they aren't all the same and moving your problem between them works wonders.

Answer (score 27):

Numerical analysis: The purpose of computing is insight, not numbers. — Richard Hamming (1962)

Comment: There's also: The purpose of computing numbers is not yet in sight. — Richard Hamming (1971)

Answer (score 27):

One of my favorites:

"Algebraic topology is the "art" of Not doing the integral"

Answer (score 27):

Homotopy theory is an attempt to do homological algebra in non-abelian categories.

Comment: Hmmmmmm-any of the topologists want to take issue with this one as an oversimplification? 

Comment: really andrew? If anything most answers are vast oversimplifications. This one does in fact have some meat to it though. Quillen's theory of model categories is precisely what (I think) is being referenced. With a simplicial model structure you can do resolutions like you would in homological algebra.

Comment: Quillen's first paper on model categories was called "Homotopical Algebra" to emphasize this analogy. But homotopy theory was a subject before that sort of abstract homotopy theory came in, and although derived-functor methods are an important tool in the homotopy theory of spaces they aren't what it's all about.

Comment: It's actually one of the better slogans here. 

Comment: Although I'd apply it more to model category theory.

Answer (score 22):

Algebraic geometry: CommRing behaves a lot like Set<sup>op</sup>.

Answer (score 20):

The bonniest mot I can ever recall — from some graduate algebra course:

- ***"Free" is just another word for nothing to do on the left.***

Comment: In algebra, "freedom's just another word for nothing left to lose". :-)

Answer (score 19):

**Representation theory of Lie groups:** there is a whole world between $\mathrm{Sym}^n V$ and $\wedge^n V$. (Okay, this is an oversimplication - I am talking about the representations of $\mathrm{GL}\left(V\right)$ here, but this is the fundament of all other classical groups.)

**Constructive logic:** if you can't compute it, shut up about it. (At least some forms of constructive logic. Brouwer seemed to have a different opinion iirc.)

**Homological algebra:** How badly do modules fail to behave like vector spaces?

**Gröbner basis theory:** polynomials in $n$ variables can be divided with rest (at least if you have some $O\left(N^{N^{N^{N}}}\right)$ of time)

**Finite group classification:** what works for Lie groups will surely be even simpler for finite groups, right? ;)

**Algebraic group theory:** In order to differentiate a function on a Lie group, we just have to consider the group over $\mathbb R\left[\varepsilon\right]$ for an infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ ($\varepsilon^2=0$).

**Semisimple algebras:** The representations of a sufficiently nice algebra mirror a structure of the algebra itself, namely how it breaks into smaller algebras.

**$n$-category theory:** all the obvious isomorphisms, homotopies, congruences you have always been silently sweeping under the rug are coming back to have their revenge.

**Modern algebraic geometry (schemes instead of varieties):** let's have the beauty of geometry without its perversions.

How many of these did I get totally wrong?

Comment: I'm sure at least some people would reverse the last one...

Comment: D Grinberg, surely you meant ‘Lie *group*’ rather than ‘Lie algebra’ in the finite-group classification?

Comment: @n-category theory: I would definitively watch that movie! :-D

Comment: I like how the smiley ";)" is key to the description of finite group classification ;)

Answer (score 18):

Analytic Number Theory: log log log log log...

Did I see that quote in Havil's book [*Gamma*](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7494.html)?

Answer (score 18):

Renormalization in quantum field theory: "just because something is infinite doesn't mean it is zero". (Explanation: this was said in about 1950 when regularization/renormalization was discovered as a way of getting sensible non-zero values for formally infinite expressions.)

Comment: I was going to make a snarky comment about typos, but then your explanation made me think it wasn't a typo after all.  As someone who doesn't know anything about renormalisation, I ask snark-free:  is the quote really "… doesn't mean it *is* zero" rather than "… doesn't mean it *isn't* zero"?

Answer (score 17):

Logic teaches us that (untrained) intuition is often wrong, but that when it's right, it's for the wrong reason.

Comment: Deeper than it looks like at first sight, you shouldn't vote it down so easily!

Comment: I disagree that most logic is true for the wrong reasons. I think many people just haven't developed good intutitions about logic.

Comment: Studying logic seems to be equivalent to developing good intuitions about logic.  I'll edit this to read "untrained intuition"; maybe that is a better way to put it.

Answer (score 13):

Noncommutative Ring Theory: If it is not modules, then it is idempotents.

Comment: This seems a bit too cryptic for me...

Comment: Well, when you try to prove some (non too-far-fetched) fact in Noncommutative Ring Theory, you have roughly two main families of techniques to resort to:

1) Techniques which involve modules. Facts about one-sided ideals, the categorical viewpoint, K-theory over the monoid of finitely generated projective modules, homological tools... 

2) Techniques which involve idempotents. Taking corners, rings with local units, rings with enough idempotents, the Peirce decomposition...

That's what I tried to comprise by this sentence ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Topological Vector Spaces: You can make an infinite dimensional space have every nice property of finite dimensional spaces- but not all of them at once.

Answer (score 12):

Geometric group theory: the large-scale geometry of a group is invariant under quasi-isometry.

Answer (score 9):

Configuration space integrals: Don't take limits- compactify!

Dror Bar-Natan explained this punchline to me when I was just starting grad school.

Answer (score 8):

"set theory is the study of well-foundedness" - A.R.D Mathias

Answer (score 8):

Terry Tao, [in a post on *Google Buzz*](https://profiles.google.com/114134834346472219368/posts/WNYxf8DHXVi), has given an overview of mathematics in the form of multiple "punch-lines" of the requested variety.

Here are three examples from Tao's post:

> - Algebra is the mathematics of the "equals" sign, of identity, and of the "main term"; analysis is the mathematics of the "less than" sign, of magnitude, and of the "error term".
> - Algebra prizes structure, symmetry, and exact formulae; analysis prizes smoothness, stability, and estimates.
> - Most of geometry would not be classified as either algebra or analysis, but simply as geometry.

Definitely Tao's aphorisms are thought-provoking and inspiring ... but are they useful ?  Don't ask me!  :)

---

Partly inspired by Tao's essay, here is a one-sentence [definition of quantum mechanics](http://faculty.washington.edu/sidles/ENC_2011/index.html#forGilKalai) (as optimized for systems engineers)  …

> - Quantum mechanics is the algebraic geometry of $n$-particle Hamiltonian flows and Lindbladian compressions as pulled-back onto the natural $r$-indexed stratification of $r$'th secant varieties of $n$-factor Segre varieties whose $r\to\infty$ limit is … $n$-particle Hilbert space.

… and it turns out to be very useful (and great fun) to rewrite standard quantum physics texts like [Charles Slichter's *Principles of Magnetic Resonance*](http://faculty.washington.edu/sidles/ENC_2011/index.html#Slichter) based upon this one sentence definition.

Joseph Landsberg's recent *Bull. AMS* review "[Geometry and the complexity of matrix multiplication](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2008-45-02/S0273-0979-08-01176-2/home.html)" (2008), which has been praised in multiple MathOverflow posts, provides an overview of the broad utility—despite their unwieldy name—of  stratifications of secant varieties of Segre varieties (which extends far beyond quantum physics).

Comment: I find Tao's slogans much better than yours -- sorry. 

Answer (score 7):

About Sobolev spaces, Meyers and Serrin theorem [H = W](https://www.pnas.org/content/51/6/1055)

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested, the paper is http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=164252 by Meyers and Serrin

Comment: And the "H" is  a cyrillic *en*, that stands for S.M.Nikolsky.

Comment: But this slogan explains *nothing*. 

Comment: @PietroMajer Do you have a reference for this fact? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See Willie Wang's comment. I added a link.

Answer (score 7):

Geometric representation theory: keep translating the problem until you run into Hard Lefschetz, then you are done.

Comment: This is intriguing. I'd like to see more examples.

Answer (score 6):

I'll offer two punchlines for Galois Theory.

1. There's a one-to-one, order-reversing correspondence between intermediate fields of a finite, normal, separable extension $K$ of $F$, and subgroups of the group of automorphisms of $K$ fixing $F$.
2. A polynomial is solvable in radicals if and only if the Galois group of its splitting field is a solvable group.

Answer (score 5):

Algebraic Topology: Geometry is hard, and Algebra is easy so...

(I am sure this applies to many other fields, and certainly algebra is hard.)

Answer (score 5):

Etale cohomology - you can apply fixed-point theorems from algebraic topology to Galois actions on varieties.

Comment: Though I could imagine thinking of a more eloquent rephrasing.

Comment: It's not bad though. Better than a lot of other answers. 

Answer (score 4):

Analysis: Allez en avant, et la foi vous viendra (D'Alembert, to a student who had difficulty in believing the calculus of infinitely small. Translation: go on, and faith will be bestowed on you :)

Answer (score 4):

**Four-Dimensional Smooth Manifolds**: Whitney's trick gone wrong.

Answer (score 3):

- ***Generating functions are the 19th Century analog of addressable memory.***

Answer (score 3):

Nonlinear optimization: Newton's method beats everything else (when it works); when it doesn't, do something that looks like Newton's method.

Answer (score 3):

Quantization: First quantization is a mystery, second quantization is a functor (Edward Nelson)

Comment: Where does he say that?

Answer (score 3):

Representation theory of compact groups: The representation theory is the same as for finite groups, only that there might be infinitely many isomorphism classes of irreducible representations.

(That's the Peter Weyl Theorem!)

Perhaps it would be  a much better question, to interpret a well known theorem in one sentence!

Comment: Aren't there *always* infinitely many isoclasses in the infinite case?

Comment: Of course, $L^2(G)$ should be an inifinite dimensional Hilbert space, if $G$ is not finite. Hence Peter Weyl tells you that this is indeed so, but finite groups are compact, so I do not see a wrong statement in my answer. Btw amuch more interesting question, does this imply that every compact infiniten group has infinitely many conjugacy classes?

Answer (score 2):

Linear algebra: everything can be explained by a linear system.

Comment: explained, or approximated?

Answer (score 2):

Navier-Stokes Equations: Energy estimates and more energy estimates.

*I suppose this goes for most non-linear PDEs

Answer (score 2):

Another favorite of mine …

- ***Redundancy is the essence of information.***

Answer (score 2):

**Set theory without choice:** You have no choice, but to wonder...

**Forcing:** If it doesn't not fit, force it.

**Large cardinals:** "If you want more you have to assume more." (Dana Scott)

Answer (score 2):

Additive combinatorics: Any two attempts to define what it means for a finite set to be `additively structured' will be approximately equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Number Theory : Arithmetic properties (such as number of rational solutions) of geometric objects (such as elliptic curves) are often reflected in analytical functions (such as L-functions) associated to those objects i.e. geometry reveals its arithmetic analytically.

Answer (score 1):

Algebraic geometry is the study of the intrinsic properties of any mathematical object which can be locally described by polynomial equations.

Or

Algebraic geometry is *not* about solving systems of polynomial equations, rather it's about studying the intrinsic properties thereof.

Answer (score 1):

Dirichlet forms: a symmetric Markov process is a self-adjoint operator is a closed symmetric form is a Markovian semigroup.

(I've left out a lot of hypotheses, but the essence is that all these are in correspondence, and the properties of any one appear in the others.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this belongs on this list too:

The *theory of groups* is a branch of mathematics in which one does something to something and then compares the results with the result of doing the same thing to something else, or something else to the same thing.    – [James Newman](http://www.mathacademy.com/pr/quotes/index.asp?ACTION=TOP&VAL=group%20theory)

Comment: I don't get it. 

Comment: @Todd Trimble If you study groups by their actions on sets, "$x^g$" is "doing g to x". Natural questions are like "when does $x^g = x^h$?" i.e. when does  doing something different on the same thing give the same result?  

Answer (score 1):

Morse Theory: *opus dynamicum maxime*.

Answer (score 1):

Harmonic analysis: The integral operator with the kernel (blank space to fill in) is bounded from (blank space to fill in) to (blank space to fill in).

(communicated by Mark Rudelson)

Answer (score 1):

Probability/Statistical mechanics:

Take a probabilistic model (possibly complicated, involving huge state space, describing a complex system) and rescale it suitably, such that in the limit a simpler "macroscopic" object emerges;

if the latter is still random it's a central limit theorem, if it's deterministic it's a law of large numbers, if you look at fluctuations from the latter it's large deviations; if it is largely independent on the details of the starting probabilsitc model, you have a universality phenomenon (and are happy because when modelling your real system you were forced to add some assumptions just for mathematical comfort); if it changes qualitatively when playing with a parameter of the original model you have a phase transition and want to know the critical values of the parameter.

Answer (score -3):

QFT — every expression converges after a Wick rotation.

Comment: Wick rotation isn't what leads to convergence.  A better sentence might be "Large size asymptotics of the moments of regularized path integrals are independent of the choice of regularization."