# Notations - Hardy and Sobolev Spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, notation

After some confusion on my part, I wanted to know is there a profound mathematical reason why both Hardy spaces and Sobolev spaces are denoted by $H^p$(1). Is it just coincidence? Does it have any historical meaning?

Note: Granted that a Sobolev space of $k$ derivative all in $L^p$ will not be denoted this way, but usually when $p=2$ then it is omitted, and we are left with $H^k$.

Comment: according to this earlier [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90527/history-of-sobolev-space-notations), the letter $H$ is used for the $p=2$ Sobolev space only because it's a Hilbert space.